# Can one do the equivalent of `pread(fd, buf, size, offset)` from the shell prompt?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I'd like to do the equivalent of what I can do in C via:

```
pread(fdesc, tgtbuf, size, file_offset);
```

or the combination:

```
lseek(fd, file_offset, SEEK_SET);
read(fd, tgtbuf, size)
```

as a *shell command*.

For *some* sizes/offsets, one can use:

```
dd if=file bs=size skip=$((file_offset/size)) count=1
```

That works ... but *only* if `file_offset` is divisible by `size`. Which isn't sufficient for my usecase, unfortunately.

The device I'm attempting to read from is "blocked" in 8-byte units for `read` but allows (requires) byte offsets for `seek`. `dd` always reads in units of `bs`/`ibs` but *also* always seeks in these units, which in my case is mutually exclusive.
I know I can do this via perl/python/C/... - but is there a way to do this from a simple shell script ?

**EDIT:** Since it was suggested to use `dd bs=1 count=8 ...` here - NO THIS DOES NOT WORK. `strace` it and you'll see that this does:

```
$ strace -e lseek,read dd if=/dev/zero bs=1 skip=1234 count=8
[ ... ]
lseek(0, 1234, SEEK_CUR)                = 0
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
read(0, "\0", 1)                        = 1
```

Which is *not* what I need - it *must be a single* `read()`.

**Edit2:**

The device (`/dev/cpu/<ID>/msr`) I'm trying to read from is strange in the sense that the offset is treated as an `index number`, but you'll always have to read eight bytes else the driver gives `EINVAL` on `read`.
But *every index* returns a different 8-byte value, so you cannot "reconstruct" reading from offset `x+1` by reading `x` and `x+8` and extracting the bytes. This is highly unusual ... but it's the way `/dev/cpu/<ID>/msr` works in Linux.

Comment: bs=size : size can be 1 byte, or more ... (it is an indication to dd on how to access the device, but for a file you can use whatever you need.. it's usually more efficient reading blocks of larger sizes, though)

Comment: after edit2 : are you sure you don't want to use the C program ? ^^  http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/qemu-devel/2012-09/msg01336.html  and    http://weichong78.blogspot.fr/2010/04/reading-msr.html

Comment: I know how to do this in a C program ... that's not the question ;-) but yes, the first link you gave describes exactly the problem I'm trying to overcome here.

Comment: using dd for this seems unlikely to work at best, and a big waste of time if you can have proper tools instead... dd can't do everything (and this device sure is using a weird interpretation of "seek" ! It's the one at fault, here, really...)

Comment: `msr-tools` (https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/cpu/msr-tools/) provides the thing ... _if one has it_. As said, irksome this cannot be done with standard UN*X command line tools. Ho-hum :(

Answer (score 2):

bs=size : size can be 1 byte, or more ... (it is an indication to dd on how to access the device, but for a file you can use whatever you need.. it's usually more efficient reading blocks of larger sizes, though)

try:

```
dd if=file bs=1 skip=whateveryouneed count=8  #to read 8 bytes starting at whateveryouneed
```

if (contrary to what you seem to state in the question) you can only seek to multiple of 8 (and read 8 bytes from there):

```
dd if=file bs=8 skip=X count=1  #to read 8 bytes starting at whateveryouneed
  #X being: whateveryouneed / 8  (ex:  echo "4000 / 8" | bc )
```

(as I say in my comment, I really have troubles to imagine a device that allows you to seek anywhere, and force you to read 8 bytes from anywhere, if anywhere is not also a multiple of 8 ... but, hey, anything is possible ^^ If so, you'll need another tool than dd, i'm afraid)

If it really is so weird: extract 2 blocks of 8 bytes around the adress you need, and then extract the exact part you need from it :

```
blockoffset=$(($address/8))
blockstart=$(($blockoffset*8))
shift=$(($address - $blockstart))
if [ "$shift" -eq 0 ]
   dd if=file bs=8 skip=$blockoffset count=1 > final
else
   dd if=file bs=8 skip=$blockoffset count=2 > bigger #we read 2 blocks from blockoffset  
   dd if=bigger bs=1 skip=$shift count=8 > final
fi
```

Comment: Yes it reads eight bytes ... in eight single-byte reads. Which for the device I'm attempting to read from is a no-no, the read must happen as a single eight-byte-read.

Comment: are you sure you can seek to a non-multiple of 8 and read 8 from there? seems really weird to me...

Comment: Yes ... see my `strace` above, that's what `dd` does. It'll do `read(fd, buf, 8)` _only if_ you said `bs=8`. In which case ... you can also _only seek_ in units of eight bytes.

Comment: a workaround is to take 2 blocks of 8 bytes around the adress you seek, and then excerpt the exact part you need...

Comment: I amended the answer to provide this workaround... hope it helps (I couldn't try it ... shift may need to be tweaked?)

Comment: The workaround is unfortunately not sufficient for the specific device I'm trying to access. Yes, it's written "funkily" - in a way, the seek offset is the "index number", and every index provides eight bytes.

Comment: re, seek to a non-multiple of 8 and read 8 from there ... exactly. That's how `/dev/cpu/<ID>/msr` behaves. It's "scaling differently" for seek offsets and (the sizes of) read.

Answer (score 1):

Given the amount of trouble you've gone to already, just put the C code into an executable program.  Or get really ambitious and make the program into a bash extension with "enable -f pread.so pread"

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html

likely over the top.  A separate program is easier.